# Are there guidelines for citing and attributing an answer?

Tags: discussion, moderation

In an answer to this question,

[How do I tell a roommate I'm not renewing his lease?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/11656/how-do-i-tell-a-roommate-im-not-renewing-his-lease),

I've tried to attribute each section to the relevant author that was cited in an article - I also gave the link to the article itself.

After reading a bunch of articles to try and post the best answer to OP's question, I thought that one particular article - the one I've used - does a great job of it already, so I mostly just changed a few lines from each section's quote, in order to fit the context of the OP's question.

Have I attributed the quotes from the article properly? Is there anything I should change?

For instance, would giving the source at the end of my answer sufficient -- or should I follow each quote with an attribution to someone (like I've currently done)?

Comment: Try meta.se, or the help center.

Comment: If you're looking for advise on properly citing sources perhaps [writing.se] could help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general guideline is that material which is not our own creation must be highlighted with quote formatting and attributed to the ***person*** who said or wrote it, with a link to the specific page online so that we can read it in its original context.

If the whole article was written by one person and all your quotes were written by the same person then it is usually sufficient to attribute *once* to that person and post the link to the source.

However in your answer, the different quotes were already attributed to different people within the original article so your method of ***attributing each highlighted extract 
to the specific person and then posting the source article link*** makes things extremely clear for the reader and is very appropriate here.

For more details see the Meta.SE pages regarding Stack Exchange policy on how to present material belonging to another source. The standard guidelines for attribution when *other sites reuse* material originally generated ***on Stack Exchange*** reflect our expectations of appropriate practice and could just as well guide us when we quote others:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/